# Translation probem with i18next

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next

I'm switching from a single file with all languages to one file per language using i18next.

This is the `translation.json` file

```json
{
    "section":{
        "title":"wello world"
    }
}
```

This is the export of `home.js`

```js
export default withTranslation('translation')(Home);
```

This is the backend section of the i18next.init

```js
backend: {
    loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
}
```

Is it possible to use `t('title')` instead of `t('section.title')` for the text?

I can't change `translation.json`.

Comment: I18next doesn't support such feature.

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly possible, but i18next-http-backend has a parse function: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend#backend-options

Maybe you can try to manipulate the data, to match your needs.